# How to load locally stored MP4 video

Tags: angularjs, html, video, ionic-framework

I have downloaded a MP4 video for testing purposes but I am not able to watch it even after adding the crosswalk plugin. This is what I get:

```
Cannot GET /media/big_buck_bunny.mp4
```

This is my code, which is running fine for a youtube hosted video:

```
<div class="card">
    <ion-item>
        <div class="video-container">
             <iframe ng-src="media/big_buck_bunny.mp4" frameborder="0" width="560" height="315"></iframe>
        </div>
    </ion-item>
</div>
```

Test video was downloaded from here:

http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/tests/video.html

And this is the tutorial I have followed:

https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/01/embed-video-ios-android-ionicframework-app/

EDIT: It seems I was placing videos in the wrong directory (not sandboxed). Nevertheless, it now complains about broken or corrupt file (message is in spanish so I don't know if translation is correct).

Comment: can you give us the actual error message and ideally a link to a demonstration of the problem

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, I finally managed to make it work. I don't reallly know where the problem was, but using the "video" tag solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I managed to do it using the "video" tag and tested it on different Android (which seems to be the problematic plattform) and everything works fine:

```
<video width="100%" autoplay="autoplay" controls style="margin-top: 50px; margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <source src="media/sample.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <p>Your browser does not support H.264/MP4.</p>
```